# Не отображается русский текст в php-форме

Tags: php, html, кодировка

Там, где английские буквы, все нормально, но там, где русские - получаются какие-то кракозябры. Насколько понимаю, что-то не так с кодировкой, но в meta вроде бы прописал все что надо, не помогло.

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Обработка форм</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name = "test" action = "check.php" method = "post">
            <label>Имя: </label><br>
            <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Имя" /><br>
            <label>Email: </label><br>
            <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Email" /><br>
            <label>Сообщение: </label><br>
            <textarea name = "message" cols = "40" rows = "20" ></textarea><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "done" value = "Готово" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А что такое "php форма"? Скрипт отдающий эту форму, или скрипт принимающий данные из этой формы?

Comment: Возможно я не правильно выразился, под словосочетанием php-форма - я подразумевал код описанный выше

Answer (score 0):

У меня всё нормально отображается, какая у вас ОС/Браузер?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Обработка форм</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name = "test" action = "check.php" method = "post">
            <label>Имя: </label><br>
            <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Имя" /><br>
            <label>Email: </label><br>
            <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Email" /><br>
            <label>Сообщение: </label><br>
            <textarea name = "message" cols = "40" rows = "20" ></textarea><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "done" value = "Готово" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```